# Hibernate, add the .hbm.xml file to the cfg.xml file

Tags: hibernate, jsp, exception, tomcat, hbm

i need some information

what is a hbm.xml file ??? i know just *.hbm files

and how to add the .hbm.xml file to the cfg.xml file ???

i want to know that cuz i get an error when im trying to run my jsp and they said you have to add the .hbm.xml file to the cfg.xml file !!

this is the error :

```
exception
```

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: net.sf.hibernate.MappingException: No persister for: MyDB.student
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:531)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:332)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

cause mère

javax.servlet.ServletException: net.sf.hibernate.MappingException: No persister for: MyDB.student
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:901)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:830)
    org.apache.jsp.JSP.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:68)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:416)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:332)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

cause mère

net.sf.hibernate.MappingException: No persister for: MyDB.student
    net.sf.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:347)
    net.sf.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.getClassPersister(SessionImpl.java:2690)
    net.sf.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.getPersister(SessionImpl.java:2697)
    net.sf.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveWithGeneratedIdentifier(SessionImpl.java:763)
    net.sf.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:738)
    org.apache.jsp.JSP.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:75)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:68)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:416)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:332)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. hbm files are normally XML and normally have the extension .hbm.xml . If you named them just .hbm, you broke convention.
2. You don't have to map them all from hibernate.cfg.xml - you can do it programmatically or via Spring.
3. If you want to though, you just add them similar to this

   ```
       <mapping resource="org/hibernate/auction/Item.hbm.xml"/>
       <mapping resource="org/hibernate/auction/Bid.hbm.xml"/>
   ```